# OrientDb transaction error

Tags: java, transactions, orientdb

I'm evaluating several NoSQL databases, including OrientDB. I'm a OrientDB newbie, trying to write a multi-threaded test that stresses OrientDB transactions.

Here is the code (imho too long to be included here): https://github.com/PeterKnego/nosql-benchmark/blob/master/orientdb/src/main/java/net/nosql_bench/OrientDbSimpleTransact.java

It's a simple standalone test that uses a number of parallel threads that read an entity, increases the value of `number` field and them save the entity, all inside a transaction.

It creates a lot of contention on one entity - that's the whole point. It kind of works, detects contention most of the time and properly rolls back the transaction.

I'm testing this on a locally installed OrientDB 2.0-rc2, client connects to it via a `remote` protocol.

Any ideas why sometimes transaction collisions get detected, while sometimes they pass?

Comment: Your answer is here [OrientDB multi-version-concurrency control](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Java-Multi-Threading#multi-version-concurrency-control)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. The code uses transactions as described in docs.  The problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I'd recommend using a **connection pool**. ThinkerPop API includes factory implementation for both, document and graph connections. Every time you create a new thread you should probably acquire an instance to the connection pool.

For documents you have

```
ODatabaseDocumentPool pool = new ODatabaseDocumentPool("plocal:/temp/mydb");
OrientGraph g = new OrientGraph(pool.acquire());
```

For graph database it is even simpler

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:/temp/mydb").setupPool(1, 10);
OrientGraph txGraph = factory.getTx();
```

I'd try using a pooled connection to the database to see if this error persists, and remember to close the database instance once you have finished using it.

Check out this link http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Factory.html